# How to remove duplicates when sorting by field with postgresql TEXT type?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sorting

Let's say there is a profile plate with the fields nickname, full name. The nickname field is text. I want to sort this table by the TEXT field in a case insensitive manner, removing the duplicates of the nickname field. How should I do it?

With such a record

```
CREATE TABLE profile(
    nickname text,
    fullname text );

SELECT DISTINCT * FROM profile
ORDER BY  lower(nickname)
```

An error is displayed `ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select  list`

Unfortunately, lower () does not work with varchar (it writes an error related to utf8) and there is no way to use the CITEXT extension. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  What does "removing the duplicates of the nickname field" mean?

Comment: @Anton provide some sample data and the expected results. After reading your question again i am not sure i got it right. perhaps a simple `distinct on` would suffice ..

Comment: I consider this a bug in PostgreSQL. `nickname` does exist in the select list, so the DBMS should be able to sort it by `lower(nickname`). It does work by the way, if we remove `DISTINCT`, so PostgreSQL gets confused somehow, when `DISTINCT` is used in combination with `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message suggests, you cannot order by a column that does not exist. That being said, add the lower function to the select clause and it should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT lower(nickname), fullname 
FROM profile
ORDER BY lower(nickname);
```

In case you want to arbitrarily eliminate duplicated nicknames try `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (lower(nickname)) * 
FROM profile
ORDER BY lower(nickname);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT lower(nickname),* FROM profile
ORDER BY  lower(nickname);
```

as the error written